# Avoid rewriting common function for multiple classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following situation: I have a class `Application` that wraps `data` given to it in header and footer and adds `checksum` to make a `packet`. `TCP` inherits from `Application` and does the exact same procedure with the `packet` obtained from `Application`(i.e, it calls `super` to `make_packet` and then makes it's own).

Since the `make_packet` code is the same for both the classes, except for header and footer values, I tried to to use closures, like below. 
The important line below is the `self.packet = cls_name.header + self.packet + cls_name.footer` in the `cmake_packet`:

```
def make_make_packet(cls_name):
    def cmake_packet(self):
       self.packet = cls_name.header + self.packet + cls_name.footer
       checksum = self.packet[::-1]
       self.packet += checksum
       return self.packet

    return cmake_packet()


class Application:
    header = footer = "001101"

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.packet = data

    make_packet = make_make_packet(Application)


class TCP(Application):
    header = footer = "110011"

    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__(data)
        self.packet = super().make_packet()

    make_packet = make_make_packet(TCP)
```

and to send a packet of data across a network, I just call:

```
# data is something like "010"
tlayer = TCP(data)
# or send()
print(tlayer.make_packet())
```

The problem is that the above definition gives an error because when `make_make_packet(Application)` is called, `Application` is not yet defined.

Is there a way to solve this problem without repeating the function for several classes, **and without using self.header** (which doesn't work here anyway)

**Note:** `make_packet()` needs to be called twice for each `TCP` packet that is made, not once(OSI seven layer model). First `Application` wraps the raw data in a packet, which is then further wrapped in a bigger packet by `TCP` by adding it's own headers.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just use inheritance for the `packet` method.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I didn't get you, can you please elaborate? `packet` is not a method, it's a instance variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class attributes are also accessible by `self.`.

```
class Application:
    header = footer = "001101"

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.packet = data

    def make_packet(self):
       self.packet = self.header + self.packet + self.footer
       checksum = self.packet[::-1]
       self.packet += checksum
       return self.packet


class TCP(Application):
    header = footer = "110011"

    def __init__(self, data):
        data = Application(data).make_packet()
        super().__init__(data)
```

Comment: Just use `self.make_packet()` in `TCP.__init__`.